# C program failing to insert to file contents the previously read contents

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I have this problem in my c program when I start to reinsert the contents of my file and save a new one. It fails in the while loop and i don't understand why it does that if i have some contents to reinsert from it.

**here's my code:**
'''

```
void init(){
    char pn[30],pd[30],pp[30];
    if ((flptr = fopen("MASTER.dat","r+")) == NULL) { 
        printf("Couldnt Get Cred");
        return;
    }
    fscanf(flptr,"%s %s %s",pn,pd,pp);


    while(!feof(flptr)){
        r = (struct Records *) malloc(sizeof(struct Records));
        int fr = fscanf(flptr,"%s %s %f",r->PartNum,r->PartDesc, &r->PartPrice);
        if(fr == EOF){
            printf("HERE");
            break;
        }

        if(head == NULL){
           head = r;
         }
         else{
             tail->next = r;
         }
         tail = r;
         }

         fclose(flptr);
    }


void put(){
    if ((flptr = fopen("MASTER.dat","r")) == NULL) { 
        printf("Couldnt Get Cred");
        return;
    }

    r = head;
    fprintf(flptr,"PartNumber PartDescription PartPrice\n");

    while (r != NULL){
        fprintf(flptr,"%s %s %f\n", r->PartNum, r->PartDesc, r->PartPrice);
        r = r->next;
    }

    fprintf(flptr,"Changes SAVED.");
    fclose(flptr);
}
```

Comment: What does "it fails" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function *put* you open the file to read it, not to write, so your *fprintf* will have no effect and the file not be even created

> ```
> if ((flptr = fopen("MASTER.dat","r")) == NULL) {
> ```

must be

```
if ((flptr = fopen("MASTER.dat","w")) == NULL) {
```

If later you try to read that non existing file with *init* you will not success

Out of that *put* and *init* use the global variable *r* and modify it, I encourage you to use a local variable to avoid possible problems

---

Why do you open file file with "r+" in *init* while you only read it ?

---

When you read string through *(f)scanf* I encourage you to limit the length to not write out of the receiver with an undefined behavior, and to always check the result, so for instance replace

> ```
> fscanf(flptr,"%s %s %s",pn,pd,pp);
> ```

by

```
if (fscanf(flptr,"%29s %29s %29s",pn,pd,pp) != 3) {
  printf("invalid file contain\n");
  return;
}
```